# managed bean use another managed bean

Tags: java, jsf-1.2, managed-bean

i have to  managed beans ( recruiter and offfer ) but i do not  know  how  to  get recruiter's offers imean a list of  offers submited by the recruiter on the recruitment app (my project)

i have  a model bean that i called : MB_recruiter  such as :

```
  public class MB_recruiter {
// attributes
.
.
.
List <MB_offer> My offers;
// rest..
}
```

and the  other Model bean  is  MB_offer

```
 public class MB_offer {



}
```

the problem is that i can not accessing the list of offers when  i try to  read it in a datatable component  even if  i am sure  it  initialised because i intialise the  recruiter model  (data)  by a controller bean used by the login mechanism !
help please  :3

Answer (score 0):

You can use managedProperty to get values from one another. Your beans have to be on same degree or the one being used on the other should have above Scope.

If u need to access to that list in another Bean, lets say ExampleBean, you can have a managed property that u call in ExampleBean to access ManagedBean MB_Recruiter and its variables.

For that ExampleBean needs to have same or lower scope.(RequestScope

```
@ManagedBean(name="example")
@RequestScope
public class ExampleBean{

@ManagedProperty("#{mb_recruiter}")   //Assuming MB_Recruiter name is "mb_recruiter"
private MB_Recruiter mb_Recruiter;

/*Don't forget to insert proper Setter and Getter here otherwise it won't work */

}
```

Now you are free to call in ExampleBean, the methods in MB_Recruiter or variables(if they are not private).

Hope it was what u were looking for.

It worked for me. I do it when i want to search anything of the logged user.